# How do you send checkbox data in Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to post checkbox data with Jsoup and am having a little trouble. I thought that when multiple checkboxes are selected, they are sent as an array to the server but maybe that is not the case?

This is what I thought was correct:

```
HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap<String, String>();
postData.put("checkbox", "[box1,box2,box3]");

Jsoup.connect("somesite").data(postData).post();
```

This does not seem to work properly. However, if I send only a single checkbox then I get my expected results leading me to believe my understanding of how checkbox form data sends is incorrect.

This works:

```
postData.put("checkbox", "box2");
```

Maybe HashMap is the wrong type to use. According to the Jsoup [documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#data%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) I could just call .data(key, value) multiple times but I was hoping for something a little cleaner than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple checkboxes, then presumably each checkbox has its own `name` attribute. You should then call `.data(name, value)` for each such name.

AFAIK there's no way to "collapse" these calls to `data` into a single call.

Comment: Looks like you are right. I tried using the Apache MultiHashMap but it blew up Jsoup. Didn't care to look into why it didn't like it but I will just accept it was intentional design to require .data(key, value) for multiple checkbox values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can try something like the following ?

```
 HashMap<String,String> paramHM=new HashMap<String,String>();

 ArrayList<String> checkboxVal=new ArrayList<Strnig>();
 / .. put request.getParametersValues() in this arraylist

 org.jsoup.Connection jsoupConn=Jsoup.connect(web_api).data(paramHM);

 // Multiple Call that 
 for(String item:checkboxVal){
    jsoupConn=jsoupConn.data("checkbox",item);
 }
```